# Can I save encrypted token in HTTP only cookie?

Tags: authentication, cookies, oauth, single-page-application, github-api

I'm building a single page application (SPA), which calls the GitHub API in client side with GitHub token of the users.
I want to persist the token, but saving it into browser storage (e.g. localStorage, sessionStorage, indexedDB...) from javascript is not secure due to xss.

So I thought an idea: In order to persist the token, the client (SPA) send the token to my backend API server, and the backend encrypts the token and attaches it into http-only cookie and sends it back.
When decrypting the token, the client call the backend, and the backend reads the cookie which holds the encrypted token, decrypts it, and send the raw token to the client.

I want to keep the backend as simple as possible, so I don't want to keep user sessions in backend (it requires DB to save the session information).

Is it secure?
If no, how to persist the token securely?

Comment: If you are sending it to the server why not store it on the server side itself?

Comment: As I added to the question, I want to keep the backend as simple as possible. Storing the token in server side requires DB, but the idea I thought doesn't.

Comment: In that case I think your token would be relatively secure as long as you are using encryption (and not hashing) with a private key to create the browser cookie on your server. The reason I recommended pathfix was that it will add an extra layer of security and you can store their public key and benefit out of their DB+Firewall. Also calls can be made using JavaScript directly.

Comment: @Ralph Does Pathfix pass the token to the client based on the session cookie? Or, does it simply proxy the API call from the client?

Comment: You won't be able to read a HttpOnly cookie, so there's no way to send that along to any other API.

Comment: @Evert the cookie is attached by my backend server, and read by my backend server. The client and any other server don't read the cookie.

Comment: Yes, but you mention elsewhere that you want to send the token back encrypted (which is pointless), and put it in a httponly cookie. That cookie is not readable by the client.

Comment: Yes, I know the client cannot read the cookie. The purpose of the cookie is to hold the encrypted token, which cannot be decrypted or read by the client. In order to get the token from the cookie, at first the client sends the cookie to the server, and the server reads the cookie and decrypts it, and send back the raw token as a response, which can be read by the client.

Comment: The client never saves the token in permanent storage (e.g. localStorage). After the client leaves the SPA, the token data only exists in the cookie as an encrypted data (not in the server, not in the localStorage).

Comment: I see, interesting. So if XSS is possible, don't you think that the browser can make that request anyway to exchange the encrypted token for an unencrypted one?

Comment: I mean, in the hypothetical scenario of an XSS bug. Whether the token was in localstorage, or I can ask the server for the unencrypted token, I don't think you're adding any security. But maybe you can think of a scenario where going through the server helps.

Comment: Yes, I think the token can be stolen due to a XSS bug, simply requesting the backend server to get the raw token. I want to know any idea to prevent this situation by taking advantage of going through the backend server.

Comment: Do you think a session mechanism can resolve this issue? The server creates a session id and response it to the client, and saves the token into DB. I think the token still can be stolen due to XSS bug, simply requesting the backend API with the cookie holding the session id. (Is this a form of session hijacking?)

Comment: @Yohei it proxies